# MATLAB: fastest way to do a root-mean-squared error between a vector and array of vectors

Tags: search, matlab, vector, find

I have a question regarding the fastest way to compute the RMSE between a single vector and an array of vectors. Specifically, I have a vector A representing an  point and would like to find the index in a list B of  points that A is closest to. Right now I am using:

```
    tempmat = bsxfun(@minus,A,B);
    tempmat1 = sqrt(sum(tempmat.^2,2);
    index = find(tempmat1 == min(tempmat1));
```

this takes about 0.058 seconds to calculate the index. Is there a faster way in MATLAB of doing this? I performing this calculations literally millions of times.

Many thanks for reading,
Joe

Comment: A is an [x,y,z] vector and B is an array with each row being an [x,y,z] vector. Somehow that didn't make it past the formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
tempmat = bsxfun(@minus,A,B);
tmpmat1 = sum(tempmat.^2,2);
[m,index] = min(tempmat1);
m = sqrt(m); %# optional, only if you need the actual numerical value
```

This avoids calculating `sqrt` on the whole array, since the minumum of the squared differences will have the same index. It also uses the second output of `min` to avoid the second pass of `find`.

Comment: cool, don't know why I didn't see that before! This provides about a 15% increase in speed. Is there any other MATLAB functionality I can use, or is this it? I realize it is a pretty basic computation, so I feel like the size of my list is the limiting factor.

Comment: I like @Nzbuu's suggestion (http://stackoverflow.com/a/8318513/120261). In your case, I guess it would be `A(ones(1, size(B,1)),:) - B`. Probably slower, but worth trying because who knows with Matlab, is `repmat(A, size(B,1), 1) - B`. More likely though, you need to look at the overall structure of your program to see if you can see any opportunities to cache prior results or something. If you're desperate to speed up this particular operation, you could write a MEX file in C and call it from Matlab.

Comment: a MEX file may be a viable operation. This operation is more or less the krux of my program, and like Is aid is called millions of times. The vector A changes with each iteration, so I don't think there is a way to cache any results in this case.

Comment: There was a question a while ago on distances which mentioned kd-trees (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2815279/120261). You might find that some sort of pre-processing of B allows you to calculate the minimum distance more directly.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably find that

```
tempmat = A - B(ones(1, size(A,1)), :)
```

is faster than the `bsxfun` version, unless size(A,1) is exceptionally large.

This assumes that A is your array and B is your vector. The RSS calculation implies that you have row vectors.

Also, I presume you know that you're calculating the RSS not RMS.

Comment: You're missing an end parenthesis.